# pdf reader for ipad

Tags: pdf, ios

I am looking for a good pdf reader for my ipad with the following features:

- free and ad free
- single page fullscreen mode for presentations
- works without the need to register somewhere, works offline

I don't want to annotate anything and don't want to change the pdf.

Comment: What research have you done, what were your findings, and what were the deficiencies of the products you found? With a simple Google search for "pdf reader for ipad" the first two hits - neither "sponsored" were Apple App Store entries for free PDF-reading products. As I don't use an iPad, I can't say whether they meet your criteria above other than 'free'.